# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense, nancy

I've got a custom library project which contains several `Razor` HTML files as well as `Nancy` modules. Whenever I open a ***.cshtml** file, `Intellisense` throws the following warning:

```
ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor...'
```

...although it's there and declared in `app.config`. I've reflected the dll using `ILSpy` and it shows that it doesn't have any additional dependencies that might not have been loaded correctly.

What could I do?

**Library References**

- Microsoft.CSharp
- Nancy
- Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor (custom built using System.Web.Razor, not as in the current release System.Web.Razor.Unofficial)
- Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders
- System
- System.Web.Razor

**app.config**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".cshtml"
                 type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.NancyCSharpRazorBuildProvider, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders" />
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
</system.web>

<razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="Captivate.Core.Host.Web" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="Captivate.Core.Host.Web" />
    </namespaces>
</razor>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="Nancy"/>
            <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
            <add namespace="Captivate.Server.Host.Web"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

For testing, I also created a `web.config` and copied the relevant parts into it, but that did not help either.